# What should I prepare for a postdoc interview?

Tags: postdocs, interview

I am preparing for a postdoc interview. In the invitation e-mail, they send me a paper to read beforehand. My question is that:

What do they expect from me in the interview related to the paper?

Comment: What field is this? What is the nature of the postdoc?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely they will ask you to quickly summarise the paper and then discuss strengths and weaknesses.

Usually is more important to get the idea of the paper and present your opinion on it than details.

But nobody can really predict what they will ask. It might also be worth checking if the paper comes from a competing lab or a collaborating lab (EDIT: or the lab itself!).

The most important thing (apart from the paper) is to show that you will be on fire for the proposed research (just to like it is not enough).

Comment: ...or from the interviewing lab itself, in which case they might be looking for your ideas about that topic, and interest in/willingness to work on it.

Comment: And beside this, think about nicely presenting you and what done during your theses

Comment: Thank you for comments! I have only working days to prepare. I receive the e-mail on Friday and the interview is scheduled on Tuesday next week.